# Laravel app::call('SomeController@method') not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to be able to call a method inside a controller in the following manner:

```
App::call('SomeController@method');
```

I figured it happens like this when defining a route:

```
Route::get('/route', 'SomeController@method');
```

So maybe there's an underlying mechanism I can use more generally in my code on other places in the project, turns out there is (App::call()).

The problem I'm running into is that this generates an error:

```
ReflectionException (-1)
Class SomeController does not exist

## \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php

public function build($concrete)
{
    // If the concrete type is actually a Closure, we will just execute it and
    // hand back the results of the functions, which allows functions to be
    // used as resolvers for more fine-tuned resolution of these objects.
    if ($concrete instanceof Closure) {
        return $concrete($this, $this->getLastParameterOverride());
    }

    $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);

    // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
    // an abstract type such as an Interface of Abstract Class and there is
    // no binding registered for the abstractions so we need to bail out.
    if (! $reflector->isInstantiable()) {
        return $this->notInstantiable($concrete);
    }

    $this->buildStack[] = $concrete;

    $constructor = $reflector->getConstructor();
```

I'm pretty sure I must include some stuff somewhere but since Laravel is pretty big I'm asking this community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving the full namespace like:

```
App::call('App\Http\Controllers\SomeController@method');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

```
app()->call(['\App\Http\Controllers\SomeController', 'index']);
```

where index is the name of the method. You can add a second parameter to send some data like so:

```
app()->call(['\App\Http\Controllers\SomeController', 'index'], [
   'name' => 'Strawberry'
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call the method by using the [`app()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-app) helper. Syntax is `app($fullControllerClassName)->methodYouWantToCall()`:

```
app('App\Http\Controllers\SomeController')->method();
```

Comment: This is a valid way to call a method from a resolved class, but it's not ideal because you lose dependency injection. Not sure what the helper method is, but `App::call(['App\Http\Controllers\SomeController', 'method'])` allows DI to work.